# VSCode include errors in MSYS2/clang64 environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, msys2

I am getting the following errors in VSCode on Windows using MSYS2/clang64 compiler:

> #include errors detected. Consider updating your compile_commands.json or includePath. IntelliSense features for this translation unit (D:\xxx\xxx.cpp) will be provided by the Tag Parser.C/C++(1696)

and

> cannot open source file "cstddef" (dependency of "D:\xxx\gtest\gtest.h")C/C++(1696)
> when using MSYS2 clang64 environment.

Additionally cstlib, iostream, ... aren't found as well.

Using MSYS2 mingw64 (clang or gcc) everything is working.

Part of my cmake-kits.json

```
    {
    "name": "MSYS2 clang64",
    "compilers": {
        "C": "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin\\clang.exe",
        "CXX": "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin\\clang++.exe"
    },
    "environmentVariables": {
        "CMT_MINGW_PATH": "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin"
    }
```

Comment: Did you manually set any include paths in VSC pointing to `mingw64`? In any case, normally the solution is to generate `compile_commands.json` using CMake, which should have all information intellisense needs. At least it's enough for Clangd (an alternative to stock intellisense), but I believe intellisense can parse it too.

Comment: I have the compile_commands.json. For clang64 and for the others as well. The files are identical with exception of the build folder.